# Sort multiple csv files based on two columns within a directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, sed, awk

I have multiple `.csv` files in a directory called `mydirectory`. I want to sort all these files using some bash/awk/sed command first based on `LeftChr` column and then `RightChr` column and get the `result`.

```
>Id LeftChr LeftPosition    LeftStrand  LeftLength  RightChr    RightPosition   RightStrand
1979    chr1    825881  -   252 chr2    5726723 -
5480    chr2    826313  +   444 chr2    5727501 +
5492    chr5    869527  +   698 chr2    870339  +
1980    chr2    1584550 -   263 chr1    1651034 -
5491    chr14   1685863 +   148 chr1    1686679 +
5490    chr1    1691382 +   190 chr1    1693020 +
```

result

```
>Id LeftChr LeftPosition    LeftStrand  LeftLength  RightChr   RightPosition   RightStrand
     5490   chr1    1691382 +   190 chr1    1693020 +
     1979   chr1    825881  -   252 chr2    5726723 -
     1980   chr2    1584550 -   263 chr1    1651034 -
     5480   chr2    826313  +   444 chr2    5727501 +
     5492   chr5    869527  +   698 chr2    870339  +
     5491   chr14   1685863 +   148 chr1    1686679 +
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically just need 'sort -k'

```
for f in *.csv; do
   # output of first line
   head -1 $f
   # output of any but first line, then sort after 2. then 6. column
   tail -n +2 $f | sort -k 2,6
done
```